# How did the tapes falling scene in the train trigger Ed Warren to check the tape?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-conjuring-universe, the-conjuring-2

Exactly what was the significance of the tapes falling scene in *The Conjuring 2* or what led Ed Warren to check the tape in the train?

What was the significance of the falling tapes from the luggage?

Answer (score 9):

When the tapes fell from the luggage, the reels from two tapes crossed each other and that triggered the idea in Ed Warren's mind to mix ghost voices of Janet's multiple recordings into one. And that also helped them to know the real reason of the haunting in the end.